# Finding string in row to overwrite this row of CSV using Python 2.7

Tags: python, csv

I'm following some feedback from another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148772/overwriting-a-specific-row-in-a-csv-file-using-pythons-csv-module), but have gotten stuck. I'm looking to search an existing csv file to locate the row in which a string occurs. I am then looking to update this row with new data.

What I have so far gives me an "TypeError: unhasable type: 'list'":

```
allLDR = []
with open('myfile.csv', mode='rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    #allLDR.extend(reader)
    for num, row in enumerate(reader):
        if myField in row[0]:
            rowNum = row

line_to_override = {rowNum:[nMaisonField, entreeField, indiceField, cadastreField]}

with open('myfile.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=',')
    #for line, row in enumerate(allLDR):
    for line, row in enumerate(reader):
        data = line_to_override.get(line, row)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `allDR.extend(reader)` consumes all of the input lines from the `csv.reader` object. Therefore, the `for` loop never runs, and `rowNum=row` is never executed, and `{rowNum:blah}` generates an exception.

Try commenting out the `allDR.extend(reader)` line.

As a debugging aid, try adding `print` statements inside the for loop and inside the conditional.

---

Here is a program which does what I think you want your program to do: it reads in `myfile.csv`, modifies rows conditionally based on the content of the first cell, and writes the file back out.

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', mode='rb') as ifile:
    allDR = list(csv.reader(ifile))

for row in allDR:
    if 'fowl' in row[0]:
        row[:] = ['duck', 'duck', 'goose']

with open('myfile.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    csv.writer(ofile).writerows(allDR)
```

Comment: hm...just checking--row[0] is the first column, right? that's what i'm trying to read and i'm sure that myField exists in the first column of the csv...i'm going to try your test

Comment: See recent edit for a more useful theory. In either event, `rowNum=row` is never executed.

Comment: how do I get around allLDR being empty for the csv writer?

Comment: Is the only goal of this program to modify the one line? Do you need `allDR` for any other reason?

Comment: Does the program I posted answer  your question?

Comment: yes, i'm going to accept your answer. just another newbie question in case you want to answer: is it actually necessary to rewrite the whole csv file? Any way to do this by only targeting the row and rewriting that one?

Comment: @user25976: You have to rewrite the whole file. That's how text files work. See [How to edit a file in place](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-edit-file-in-place.html).

Comment: @Rob Weird...it seems to be writing old values, actually. I didn't catch that with my hasty testing. When printing allLDR, it shows that the new values aren't taken into account

Comment: Did you happen to change `row[:] = ...` to `row = ...`? That would create the behavior you  see.